Defining $\mathcal{A}(S) = TS$ implies $\mathcal{A}$ and $T$ share the same eigenvalues. Need help with proof step.
The following exercise comes from Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, Sheldon Axler in Section 5A, exercise number 37.

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Define
$\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(V))$ by
$$
\mathcal{A}(S) = TS
$$
for each $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that the set of eigenvalues of $T$ equals the set of eigenvalues of $\mathcal{A}$.


Here, $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the set (vector space) of linear operators defined on a vector space $V$.
This is how I thought of the problem:
Let $E_T$ be the set of eigenvalues of $T$ and let $E_{\mathcal{A}}$ be the set of eigenvalues of $\mathcal{A}$. We want to show $E_T = E_{\mathcal{A}}$, which means showing

$\lambda \in E_T$ such that there exists a nonzero $v \in V$ where $Tv = \lambda v$ if and only if $\lambda \in E_{\mathcal{A}}$ such that there exists a nonzero $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ where $\mathcal{A}(S) = \lambda S$.

Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, it has a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$.
Here's what I have so far showing the backward direction:
Let $\lambda \in E_{\mathcal{A}}$. This implies there exists a nonzero $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $\mathcal{A}(S) = \lambda S$. But by definition of $\mathcal{A}$, this implies $\lambda S = TS$. That is, for all $v \in V$, we have
$$
\lambda (Sv) = T(Sv)
$$
I have to show $Sv$ is nonzero, but this is where I'm a bit confused. Do I have to show $Sv \neq 0$ for every nonzero $v$? Or can I get away with choosing some nonzero vector (say $v_1$ since it's in the basis) and conclude that there exists a nonzero $Sv_1 \in V$ such that $\lambda (Sv_1) = T(Sv_1)$?

You choose $\lambda \in E_{\mathcal A}$. You want to prove that $\lambda \in E_{T}$. By definition, you want to exhibit a non zero vector $w \in V$ such that $Tw = \lambda w$. So far, you have proved that for all $v\in V$, you have $TSv = \lambda Sv$. Thus, it is very tempting to choose $w$ of the form $Sv$ for some $v \in V$. The problem is, can you choose a $v$ such that $w := Sv$ is non zero? If so, for what reason? If you can answer this, you are done with the backward direction

@Suzet Thank you for commenting. Well, we have that $S \neq 0$. So, there must exist some $v$ such that $Sv \neq 0$ since otherwise, $S$ would be the zero operator, which is a contradiction. Is this reasoning correct?

Exactly, this is the expected justification :)

@Suzet Ah, of course! Thank you for your help.

As discussed in the comments, the backward direction has been shown. Now I show the forward direction.
Let $\lambda \in E_T$. This implies there exists a nonzero $u \in V$ such that
$$
Tu = \lambda u 
$$
We want to show there exists a nonzero $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $\mathcal{A}(S) = \lambda S$. Since $\mathcal{A}(S) = TS$, this is equivalent to showing $(TS)v = (\lambda S)v$ for all $v \in V$.
With $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ a basis of $V$, we use the linear map lemma to define $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ by
$$
Sv_j = u 
$$
for all $j = 1, \ldots, n$. Showing $S$ is in fact linear is easy to show, so I leave it out. This definition of $S$ implies that it is nonzero (since otherwise, $S = 0$ implies $Sv_j = 0v_j = 0 = u$, contradicting that $u$ is nonzero).
Moreover, we have that for any $v \in V$,
$$
v = a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n 
$$
for some scalars $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{F}$ (here, $\mathbb{F}$ is the set of real or complex numbers). Now, observe that
\begin{align}
(TS)v = T(Sv) = T(S(a_1v_1 + \cdots +a_nv_n)) &= T(a_1Sv_1+ \cdots + a_nSv_n) \\
&=T(a_1u + \cdots + a_nu) \\
&= a_1Tu + \cdots + a_nTu \\
&= a_1 \lambda u + \cdots + a_n \lambda u \\ 
&= a_1 \lambda Sv_1 + \cdots + a_n \lambda Sv_n \\
&= \lambda S (a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n) \\
&= \lambda (Sv) \\
&= (\lambda S)v
\end{align}
The above shows that $(TS)v = (\lambda S)v$ for any $v \in V$, that is, $\mathcal{A}(S) = \lambda S$ where $S$ is nonzero. This implies $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathcal{A}$ and hence, $\lambda \in E_\mathcal{A}$.
By showing both directions, we have shown $E_T = E_\mathcal{A}$.
